# How do I mitigate the security risk for Android apps created by VS tools for Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Trend Micro uncovered a [security flaw in the Cordova Android platform](http://www.securityweek.com/serious-flaw-apache-cordova-puts-android-apps-risk) that affects all versions of Cordova. While the Cordova community is working on a “tools release” for Cordova to update the default version of the Android “platform” to include the fix, is there a way to update existing projects created by VS tools?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the workaround posted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tips-and-workarounds/android/security-05-26-2015) for the Android Cordova Platform Security Issue.

Summary:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on config.xml and select “View Code”
2. When using the default version of Cordova 4.3.0, add the following under the root <widget> element in config.xml:

   `<engine name="android" version="3.7.2" />`

   …or if you opted to update to Cordova 5.0.0:

   `<engine name="android" spec="4.0.2" />`

For projects where you have already executed a build for Android on your system, you’ll also need to remove the old version of the Cordova Android platform. Follow these steps:

1. Open a command prompt and go to your Cordova project root (not the solution root).
2. Type the following commands:

   `npm install -g cordova
   cordova platform remove android`